# What are good reasons for choosing invariance in an API like Stream.reduce()?

Tags: java, java-stream, covariance, contravariance, invariance

Reviewing Java 8 `Stream` API design, I was surprised by the generic invariance on the [`Stream.reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) arguments:

```
<U> U reduce(U identity,
             BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator,
             BinaryOperator<U> combiner)
```

A seemingly more versatile version of the same API might have applied covariance / contravariance on individual references to `U`, such as:

```
<U> U reduce(U identity,
             BiFunction<? super U, ? super T, ? extends U> accumulator,
             BiFunction<? super U, ? super U, ? extends U> combiner)
```

This would allow for the following, which isn't possible, currently:

```
// Assuming we want to reuse these tools all over the place:
BiFunction<Number, Number, Double> numberAdder =
    (t, u) -> t.doubleValue() + u.doubleValue();

// This currently doesn't work, but would work with the suggestion
Stream<Number> stream = Stream.of(1, 2L, 3.0);
double sum = stream.reduce(0.0, numberAdder, numberAdder);
```

Workaround, use method references to "coerce" the types into the target type:

```
double sum = stream.reduce(0.0, numberAdder::apply, numberAdder::apply);
```

C# doesn't have this particular problem, as [`Func(T1, T2, TResult)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534647(v=vs.110).aspx) is defined as follows, using declaration-site variance, which means that any API using `Func` gets this behaviour for free:

```c#
public delegate TResult Func<in T1, in T2, out TResult>(
    T1 arg1,
    T2 arg2
)
```

What are the advantages (and possibly, the reasons for EG decisions) of the existing design over the suggested design?

Or, asked differently, what are the caveats of the suggested design that I might be overlooking (e.g. type inference difficulties, parallelisation constraints, or constraints specific to the reduction operation such as e.g. associativity, anticipation of a future Java's declaration-site variance on `BiFunction<in T, in U, out R>`, ...)?

Comment: I suspect there would make type inference harder esp as I suspect this would leave some types unsolvable without being explicit (defeating the point of type inference)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: That was my concern, too, but 1) can you prove it? :) 2) Scala knows `TraversableOnce.reduce[A1 >: A](op: (A1, A1) ⇒ A1): A1`

Comment: One way would be to write an API like this and see what happens when you try to use it.

Comment: Good point. I just tried and it would work (for my simple example). By the way, C# solved this by putting the variance on the [declaration site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534647(v=vs.110).aspx), which is much leaner anyway

Comment: @LukasEder have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418970/java-reduceleft-signature-lower-bounded-type-arguments ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Interesting, thank you! That's exactly the same discussion, although I'm not sure if I agree with the currently accepted answer, claiming that *"`A` is basically invariant"* It isn't, as I've shown with the examples in my question.

Comment: Reminds me on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32550096/why-was-unaryoperator-named-like-this#comment58845349_32550096). Requesting `UnaryOperator<T>` instead of `Function<? super T, ? extends T>` or `BinaryOperator<T>` instead of `Function<? super T, ? super T, ? extends T>` as parameter creates restrictions on the input without changing the functionality. Just because they exist. Or because “it has conceptually more weight”. Whatever reason, it’s the same for using `BiFunction<U,? super T,U>` instead of `BiFunction<? super U,? super T,? extends U>` for the accumulator function.

Comment: @Holger: Thanks for the link. That indeed seems to be the real question here. Why, apart from being an end to itself, do we have these `XYZOperator` types... Oh well...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Crawling through the history of the lambda development and isolating "THE" reason for this decision is difficult - so eventually, one will have to wait for one of the developers to answer this question.

Some hints may be the following:

- The stream interfaces have undergone several iterations and refactorings. In one of the earliest versions of the `Stream` interface, there have been dedicated `reduce` methods, and the one that is closest to the `reduce` method in the question was still called [`Stream#fold`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/file/682e571b428a/src/share/classes/java/util/streams/Stream.java#l92) back then. This one already received a `BinaryOperator` as the `combiner` parameter.
- Interestingly, for quite a while, the lambda proposal included a dedicated interface `Combiner<T,U,R>`. Counterintuitively, this was not used as the `combiner` in the `Stream#reduce` function. Instead, it was used as the `reducer`, which seems to be what nowadays is referred to as the `accumulator`. However, the `Combiner` interface was [replaced with `BiFunction` in a later revision](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/rev/433c67388856).
- The most striking similarity to the question here is found in a [thread about the `Stream#flatMap` signature at the mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-April/008970.html), which is then turned into the general question about the variances of the stream method signatures. They fixed these in some places, for example

  > As Brian correct me:
  >
  > `<R> Stream<R> flatMap(Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends R>>
  >   mapper);`
  >
  > instead of:
  >
  > `<R> Stream<R> flatMap(Function<T, Stream<? extends R>> mapper);`

  But noticed that in some places, this was not possible:

  > `T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator);`
  >
  > and
  >
  > `Optional<T> reduce(BinaryOperator<T> accumulator);`
  >
  > **Can't be fixed because they used 'BinaryOperator', But if 'BiFunction' is
  >   used then we have more flexibility**
  >
  > `<U> U reduce(U identity, BiFunction<? super U, ? super T, ? extends U>
  >   accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)`
  >
  > Instead of:
  >
  > `<U> U reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner);`
  >
  > **Same comment regarding 'BinaryOperator'**

  (emphasis by me).

---

The only justification that I found for **not** replacing the `BinaryOperator` with a `BiFunction` was eventually given in the [response to this statement, in the same thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-April/009004.html):

> BinaryOperator will not be replaced by BiFunction even if, as you said,
>   it introduce more flexibility, a BinaryOperator ask that the two parameters
>   and the return type to be the same so it has conceptually more weight
>   (the EG already votes on that).

Maybe someone can dig out a perticular reference of the vote of the Expert Group that governed this decision, but maybe this quote already sufficiently answers the question of why it is the way it is...

Comment: Thanks for your archaeology. This does explain the status quo, even if I'm a bit disappointed :)

Answer (score 1):

In my  opinion it's just that there's no real use case for the proposed *enhancement*. The proposed Javadoc has 3 more type parameters and 5 more wildcards. I guess it's enough to simplify the whole thing to the official API because regular Java developers don't want (often are not even able) to lose their mind trying to make the compiler happy. Just for the record, your `reduce()` has 165 characters in the type signature only.

Also, arguments to `.reduce()` are often supplied in the form of lambda expressions, so there's no real point in having *more versatile versions* when such expressions often contain no or very simple business logic and are therefore used only once.

<sub>For example I'm a user of your fantastic jOOQ library and also a curious Java developer that loves generics puzzles, but often I miss the simplicity of SQL tuples when I have to put wildcards in my own interfaces because of the type parameter in `Result<T>` and the kind of troubles it generates when dealing with interfaces of the record types - not that it's a jOOQ fault</sub>

Comment: *"because regular Java developers don't want (often are not even able) to lose their mind trying to make the compiler happy"* - the suggestion would be harder to read, yes, but it would make it (a bit) easier for users to "make the compiler happy". That's where variance can be so useful

Comment: If you found a real use case maybe it's worth posting it in the original question! I tried to figure one out but was not able to

Comment: I don't feel like this answers the question at all - if your claim is that it wasn't added because there was no interest please back it up with evidence from the API discussions.

Comment: How would you find any discussion on something that never happened and that nobody is interested in? It's like dinosaurs extintion: you won't find any authoritative answer or document or definitive proof

Comment: :) OK. For the sake of argument: 1) the discussion *probably* happened. You just didn't participate (and neither did I) 2) the *"nobody"* quantifier is often erroneously deduced from the *"me-myself-and-I"* existential quantifier. At this point, the question has 9 upvotes. So, you cannot possibly assert that *nobody* is interested in this. 3) *"you won't find any authoritative..."* That's what impatient people keep saying here on Stack Overflow. Then, this sort of thing happens: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23476994/521799. Be patient. Watch this question. Learn. It *is* very interesting.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how the Java process works but in JavaScript there is no way that such a feature would be added without first discussing the implementations in other languages and their implications. This was discussed - we just have to wait for the people who discussed it to show up.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: The same happens in Java / JCP. There were thousands of E-Mails containing discussions / decisions for the lambda project: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev. It's just extremely hard to find the right E-Mail, which is why asking these questions on SO is so useful.

Comment: So you are waiting for Brian Goetz to write here, once again, that there's no use case for the wildcard in that type signature. When one wants to read Goetz's words, best is to directly mail the openjdk lists (or tweet him). But I guess the network effects are not the same, and the marketing benefits a lot from having pingbacks by SO, Twitter, /r/java... I don't want to waste anyone's time. Just decide if ignore, downvote or upvote this answer, and then let's move on