# Why is the accumulator in Stream::reduce a BiFunction and not a BinaryOperator like the combiner?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reduce, functional-interface

Why is the accumulator argument in the `Stream::reduce` method a `BiFunction` and not a `BinaryOperator` like the combiner argument.

Why is its type  `BiFunction<U, ? super T, U>`? Why `T`? Should it be `BiFunction<U, ? extends U, U>`?

Comment: The question is not entirely clear, but it *might* be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680706/what-are-good-reasons-for-choosing-invariance-in-an-api-like-stream-reduce (although it rather seems to be the "opposite" question...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a combiner needed for reduce method that converts type in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308146/why-is-a-combiner-needed-for-reduce-method-that-converts-type-in-java-8)

Answer (score 8):

```
<U> U reduce(U identity,
             BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> accumulator,
             BinaryOperator<U> combiner);
```

The *accumulator* is a function that adds an element of the `Stream` (whose type is denoted by `T`) to the intermediate result of the `reduce` operation (whose type is denoted by `U`) and returns an updated result (also of type `U`).

Therefore you can't define it as a `BinaryOperator`, where the operands and result are all of the same type.

For example, you might pass as the *accumulator* in a `reduce` call a `BiFunction<Integer,String,Integer>` which is applied on a `Stream<String>` and produces the sum of the lengths of all the elements. You can't use a `BinaryOperator<Integer>` or a `BinaryOperator<String>` for that.

On the other hand, the *combiner* takes two intermediate results (both of the same type `U`) and merges them into a result whose type is also `U`. Therefore a `BinaryOperator<U>` (which extends `BiFunction<U,U,U>`) can be used.

Comment: <U> U reduce(U identity,
              BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> accumulator,
              BinaryOperator<U> combiner); , i am asking about this version of the method the accumulator is BiFunction and the signature should be ? super U. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Comment: @AhmadMoawad That's the same method signature I was referring to in my answer.